# No such column 'CustomReportId' on entity 'DashboardComponent'

Tags: reporting, soap-api, dashboard, platform-bug

We are getting this error while trying to link dashboards and reports. This field is there in sandboxes but missing in our dev orgs.

Since it is standard object, this field cannot be managed in Profile so all admins should have access to it.

These are the fields I see in `DashboardComponent` object in the devorg.

[image]

Where as in the sandbox, these are the fields I see.

[image]

Comment: standard one. To confirm this, I created branch new dev org and still same problem.

Comment: Two issues/questions. 1) Dashboard doesn't have any report id, which would link reports being used, which is what I'm after. 2) How come in sandbox DashboardComponent shows the CustomReportId (see the edited question)?

Comment: 1) When I checked the data, the name in the DashboardComponent ("Untitled Component") is not matching the report name "Accounts by Zip" so not sure if I'm seeing what you say data should show. Also I'm still puzzled that CustomReportId is there in sandbox and prod but not in devorg. 2) My admin profile has that permission so it doesn't look like a permission related issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85640/discussion-between-datasert-and-sfdcfox).